# How to keep url encoded characters in requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, request, urlencode

I want to create a POST request to a site like `mydomain.com?character=%61` using Requests library.

But if I use `requests.post(url)` with `url = 'mydomain.com?character=%61'` then it sends a POST request to `mydomain.com?character=a`. How can I keep `%61` in request instead of decoding it to `a`?

Thanks all!

Comment: How exactly did you debug this to see that it sends "a" instead of "%61"? Why is the difference important, since both really mean the same thing…?

Comment: I use proxies in post() to send it to burpsuite. In burpsuite it's change to a instead of %61 in first line. I want to change it to %61 because it's bypass something in this server to exploit a vuln

Comment: So, are you sure *at what point* it's changed? Is it being interpreted by a proxy and/or burpsuite, or is `requests` already changing it…?

Comment: i'm pretty sure about that because when I try to directly send this through post('mydomain.com?character=%61'), it's being blocked (although I only setup to block character=a). I change a to %61 directy in burpsuite and success to exploit